# how to include header and footer files usinig gwt?

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to create a webApplication with gwt and my idea is to make a header and footer files to be included in all pages. I tried to use the UiBinder for this but it dosen't work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="EM">
        <g:north size="5">
            <!-- I want to include my heaader file here -->
        </g:north>
      </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What did you try to do? Post some of your code that shows the easiest working(not working) scenario

Comment: done .. you can see now what I want.

Comment: Instead of repeating the header and footer everywhere, how about just changing the non-header non-footer part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="EM">
        <g:north size="5">
            <!-- I want to include my heaader file here -->
             <g:HTML ui:field="header">
                <OBJECT data="file_to_include.html">
                   Warning: file_to_include.html could not be included.
                 </OBJECT>
             </g:HTML>
        </g:north>
        <g:center>
            <g:DeckLayoutPanel ui:field="containerDiv" height="100%" width="100%" animationDuration="900" />
        </g:center>
      </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

EDIT: to include a html file you could just [include your header.html](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/struct/includes.html#h-7.7.4).

You would instantiate this class once and then change the content of `containerDiv`. `containerDiv` can be of whatever type you want, doesnt has to be a `DeckLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Thank's for your answer but I have an htmt file (header.html) which contain the html code for the header. I don't want to put the html code between the <g:HTML> tags, I just want to know if there is a possibility to include my header.html here.

Comment: ahh well, then put this in your question so its clear what you want. anyway i edited my answer